# How can I use a variable in a hosts spec of an ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I would like to have a playbook look up the hosts from a variable like so:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ project_prefix }}_web"
  sudo: yes
  roles:
    - common
    - ansible-role
```

Unfortunately the output I get is as follows:

```
___________________________________
< PLAY [{{ project_prefix }}_web] >
 -----------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||


skipping: no hosts matched
```

If I hardcode a hosts value, it finds them.

*I do not want to have a task call ansible_playbook.*

Comment: AFAIK your code should have worked. Variable expansion is applied to hosts tag value. Can you add a play before to debug print value of project_prefix before using it? To confirm it's set.

Comment: Spot on.  It's important to include the files where those variables are set.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AFAIK your code should have worked. Variable expansion is applied to
>   hosts tag value. Can you add a play before to debug print value of
>   `project_prefix` before using it? To confirm the variable is set.

Problem is already solved I guess, but here is some explanation.

- ansible variable expansion returns the name of the variable (like Jinja2 I think) as value when the variable is not defined.
- sometimes (I think when the expression has only the variable like `{{var}}`) it gives a clearer message like `var: undefined variable` (instead of returning the name of variable as it's value).

All in all, when you see the name of variable in/as it's value, it is likely due to teh fact that it's not defined.